# setting background image for UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, background-image

Hi I have a UIWebView and I have set background image for my UIWebView but the Problem is the image is display more time inside my UIWebView please tell how to resolve this issue.

My code.

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       [self.webview setOpaque:NO];
       [self.webview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]]];
       [self.webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"about" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];

    }
```

I Have used the above but its not displaying properly its coming half or it display more time please tell me how to resolve this issue

Comment: Do you want that image when webview loading data?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar yes i have a html file locally inmy application so i want to display the backgound image but its showing multipule times in my webview

Answer (score 0):

You can set your `UIWebView`'s background to `clearColor` and set a `UIImage` behind it:

```
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(webviewOriginX, webviewOriginY, webview.size.width, webviewSizeHeight)];
background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:background];

[self.view addSubview:background];

// init your webview here
[self.webview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor];
```

**EDIT: SAMPLE**

try to inject this small code in your `ViewController`:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    background.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    [self.view addSubview:background];

    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];

    NSString *htmlCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><title>TITLE</title><body>HELLO WORLD</body>"];

    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlCode baseURL:baseURL];
    webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [webView setOpaque:NO];

    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

Comment: @user3793919 I added a sample code, use it and you will understand the logic I am trying to implement, you will just have to fix the dimension and change the `webview.backgroundColor`